# Extending LLDB from NDK (Android Studio 3.1.3)

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, lldb

I've found a nice plugin for lldb that allows watching memory regions as images: https://github.com/carlodalmutto/ImageWatchLLDB

As I can see, this plugin was developed for Xcode and not for Android.
However, it is written in Python and therefore should be cross-platform.

I've found a directory `c:\Users\username\.lldb\` on my hard drive. Its size is about 1 Gb.

I've created following files: `c:\Users\username\.lldbinit`, `c:\Users\username\lldbinit`, `c:\Users\username\.lldb\lldbinit`, `c:\Users\username\.lldb\.lldbinit`, `c:\Users\username\.lldb\init`

All of them have the similar content:

```
script print "script print Hi from lldb"
echo "echo Hi"
```

Unfortunately I don't see any output.

I can open LLDB console and issue these commands:

```
(lldb) script print "script print Hi from lldb"
script print Hi from lldb

(lldb) echo "Hi"
error: 'echo' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'echo'.
```

This means that LLDB understands `script print` command.

Installation directory for Android Studio contains the subdirectory `bin\lldb` containing python scripts with pretty printers (file `jstring_reader.py`, `gdb\printing.py`, etc)

So, it seems possible to extend LLDB from recent NDK.

The question is: how can I add my custom plugins?

*UPDATE*. After some hacking I've found that LLDB commands, starting with the "script" string, are actually python commands:

```
(lldb) script print sys.executable
C:\Android\sdk\lldb\3.1\bin\LLDBFrontend.exe
(lldb) script print sys.version
2.7.10 (default, Feb 24 2016, 14:25:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
(lldb) script print sys.path
['C:/Android/sdk/lldb/3.1/bin', 'C:/Android/Android Studio/bin/lldb/shared/jobject_printers', 'C:/Android/sdk/lldb/3.1/lib/site-packages', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\DLLs', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\lib', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\bin', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\lldb\\3.1\\lib\\site-packages', '.', 'C:\\Android\\Android Studio\\bin\\lldb\\shared\\stl_printers', 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\share\\pretty-printers\\libstdcxx\\gcc-4.9']
(lldb) script import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
```

The first idea of installing missing modules with pip has failed.

I update my question: Are there any official guide on writing python plugins for lldb from NDK?

*UPDATE 2*. Have tried creating Anaconda virtual environment with the same python version and adding it to `sys.path`. Also failed.

```
(lldb) script os.environ['PATH']+= r'C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy;'
(lldb) script os.environ['PATH']+= r'C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Library\bin;'
(lldb) script import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ndkpy\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

*UPDATE 3*. Have found `C:\Android\Sdk\lldb\3.1\lib\lib-tk`. Tried importing Tkinter, but still no luck:

```
(lldb) script import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Android\sdk\lldb\3.1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Comment: hi have you had any luck with this or are you still working on this? Is there a way to start the python interpreter in the NDK lldb console? I've done something similar for xcode a long time ago but typing 'script' in the NDK lldb console of android studio doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to see the memory-view in android NDK while debugging, or if there is any way to do a partial memory dump in the lldb console?

Comment: No. I stopped working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme1:

Just run `command script import C:\\lldb_plugins\\chisel\\fbchisellldb.py` or `command script import C:\\lldb_plugins\\LLDB\\lldb_commands\\dslldb.py` on your lldb console in Android Studio.

Scheme2:

Create file `C:\Users\username\.lldbinit` and put the following content to this file:

```
command script import C:\\lldb_plugins\\chisel\\fbchisellldb.py
command script import C:\\lldb_plugins\\LLDB\\lldb_commands\\dslldb.py
```

And then, run `reload_lldbinit` on your lldb console in Android Studio.